# Can't Find A4Tech Webcam Driver For Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, webcam

I have a Camera A4tech P-835 Can't find The driver For Windows 8.1. Find The Official Website But No Luck. So How Should I use IT?

Comment: What happens when you plug it in? Does Windows recognize the device or not?

Comment: Is that device supported with Windows 8.1?. The driver must be given by the vendor.

Comment: @Darius When I Plug In it Shows The Device But there is warning Sign.

Comment: Not entirely sure if you tried but I have checked torrentz.eu and with just "a4tech" as a search term i found few torrents that might have the drivers included. One of the torrents was a year old and it seemed to be legit. Don't quote me on that last thing I said. :D

Answer (score 1):

The PK-835 webcam is from like 2006, and [according to the specs](http://www.a4tech.com/product.asp?m=&cid=77&scid=89&id=283) it's compatible with:

> Microsoft Windows® 98/ME/2000/XP/2003/2004

Not sure what "Windows 2004" is supposed to be, but hey. ;)

Anyhow, unless they provide a updated driver (which they don't appear to on their web site), or Windows has one built-in, you're basically out of luck and should just plan on buying a newer webcam that's compatible with (newer operating systems like) Windows 8.1.

Comment: I search alot but no way to find the driver So the same device is out late 2013 and that support win8 so I have to buy new one.